# How should I display my python interpreter in the status bar in VS code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm a beginner, this is my first day and I have no idea that how should I display my python interpreter in the status bar in VS code? I have downloaded python but this is how it's currently displaying
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQGL3.png)

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-P > Select Interpreter

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What OS are you running? Did you install Python? Do you have any experience using Python up to now? BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to install [**python**](https://www.python.org/downloads/) for your machine and install the [**Python**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension in vscode. It will be helpful to follow this [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial).

Then create a new file with the file extension `.py`.

[image]

[image]

---

Showing `Plain Text` in your status bar means you just created a new text file and you haven't selected a language for this file.

[image]

As follows, select `python`, the status bar will be displayed as python interpreter.

[image]

[image]

---

You can add this configuration in **settings.json** file, which will make vscode create new files as python language by default.

```json
    "files.defaultLanguage": "python",
```

Comment: Did my answer help you? If it is useful, you can change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.